# Religion and expanding universe

Tags: vedas, science, universe

Is there any mention in vedas,upanishadas,gita or puranas
About expanding universe not about bigbang after that

Comment: After Bigbang theory? Scientific speculation is off-topic for our site. Asking about such scientific theories and explanations is not encouraged here.

Comment: You can edit your question removing big bang theory.

Comment: @TheDestroyer OP is asking whether there is evidence in Hindu scriptures that the universe is expanding. He says it's about expansion only and not about big bang.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are references to an "expanding" characteristic of the Universe in Puranas and other texts. First of all, the Shiva-purana verse 2.5.50.29: When praising Śiva, Bhārgava says the following:

> ... 29. O sky-formed one, because you give space within and without, that this universe evolves and expands; O merciful one, it always breathes in you and naturally merges in you Hence I bow to you. ...
>   ([source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226191.html))

Another text, the Laghu-yoga-vasishtha (chapter IV part 4), has the following statement:

> It is only through the illusory Māyā which is in the one Reality of Brahman like the waves of an ocean that the whole universe expands itself, being created and preserved through this Ajñāna.
>   ([source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/laghu-yoga-vasistha/d/doc209665.html))

Finally, Surendranath Dasgupta quotes Shrikantha in his commentary on the Brahma-sutras:

> In Brahma-sūtra II.1.18,19 Śrīkaṇṭha says that the Brahman as contracted within Himself is the cause while, when by His inner desire He expands Himself, He shows Himself and the universe which is His effect. This view is more or less like the view of Vallabha, and may be regarded as largely different from the idea of Brahman as given by Śrīkaṇṭha in I.1.2.
>   ([source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/a-history-of-indian-philosophy-volume-5/d/doc210066.html))